# How to get Azure Key Vault secret using powershell with certificate auth?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

I am including a Powershell startup task on an Azure Worker Role which needs to pull a secret from Azure Key Vault. I would like to use a client certificate to authenticate Key Vault request (cert gets installed on the VM when role comes up).

I took a look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/) tutorial on azure documentation, but this needs me to write some C# methods and include bunch of nuget packages. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

See this article: [Use Azure PowerShell to create a service principal to access resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/#create-service-principal-with-certificate)

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $cert.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $appId -TenantId $tenantId
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use powershell to access the keys in Keyvault .
use the `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret` command to get the values. It has multiple parameters to suit different requirements such as get all secrets, specific secrets etc.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn868047.aspx

Details of all the keyvault module commandlets can be found here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn868052.aspx

Comment: I could not find a way to use these cmdlets using certificate auth, can you provide an example?

Comment: cert auth to access the azure account right ?? thats normal steps in powershell. am not sure how is that different in this case.

Comment: when it is run as a start up task on PaaS VM, it will not have a user or context to authenticate. I've verified with KeyVault folks, they don't support it as of now.

Comment: oh okay. just a thought .if you upload the certificate via portal , can you access it in the powershell startup task once the role is provisioned ? am not sure if the path can be predetermined. if so you can use that certificate to talk to keyvault. Also I was thinking if you can have a function app to do the keyvault call. but that is again a nice to have request at the moment. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/746